# Matlab Bar Graph - fill bars with different colours depending on sign and magnitude

Tags: matlab, graph

I am tring to shade the individual bars in a bar graph different colours, say blue for positive red for negative. I cannot find aything on the internet that works. I my code below I find every bar is coloured as per the value of the first bar, rather than separate colours for each bar:

```
c1=zeros(32,3);
c2=zeros(32,3);
for i=1:3
    c1(:,i) = linspace(r(i),w(i),32);
    c2(:,i) = linspace(w(i),b(i),32);
end
c= [c1(1:end-1,:);c2];
subplot(2,2,2)

bar(Numbers(end-7:end,1)), shading interp
caxis([-8 8]), colormap(c), colorbar
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5):

You can change the properties of the bar object to `-1/0/1` with [sign](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/sign.html), and then use a binary red/blue colormap:

```
y=rand(10,1)*3-1.5; % some data

hb=bar(y);
set(get(hb,'children'),'cdata', sign(y) );
colormap([1 0 0; 0 0 1]); % red & blue in rgb
```

[image: bar plot with binary colors]

You can find futher info [here](http://www.mathworks.nl/support/solutions/en/data/1-1T6UHS/).

EDIT: to get it shaded, you'll have to set the `cdata` appropriately in combination with [caxis](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/caxis.html):

```
y=rand(10,1)*3-1.5; % some data
hb=bar(y);

% the colormap
Mc = 16;
Nc = Mc*2+1; % number of colors, uneven so there is a neutral middle
rgb = [1 0 0;0 0 1];
cmap = [linspace(rgb(1,1),rgb(2,1),Nc)' linspace(rgb(1,2),rgb(2,2),Nc)' linspace(rgb(1,3),rgb(2,3),Nc)' ];
colormap(cmap);

% cdata
c = y;
set(get(hb,'children'),'cdata', c);
cmax = max(abs(c));
caxis([-cmax cmax]);
```

[image: bar plot with shaded colors]

Comment: For easy colordata-mapping, use the `caxis` command: `caxis([-20,20])` puts the minimum of the colorbar at -20, and the maximum at +20, ensuring symmetry around zero. So there is a simple solution after all :)

Answer (score 1):

```
figure
hold on
bar(1, 1, 'red')
bar(2, -1, 'blue')
```

Comment: Do you propose to call separate bar for each individual bar? How use this solution if number of bars is not fixed?

Comment: You would normally use a loop if the number of bars is not fixed.

Comment: Hi Gael - where would this fit into my code? The number of bars may be variable. Thanks for your help

Comment: `for i=length(Numbers)-7:length(Numbers); n = Numbers(i,1); bar(i, n, 'FaceColor', c(i)); end`

Comment: By the way, you should provide a piece of code people can run.